# How to make Pandas Series with np.arrays into numerical value?

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I am using the classical Titanic dataset. I used `OneHotEncoder` to encode surnames of people.

```
transformer = make_column_transformer((OneHotEncoder(sparse=False), ['Surname']), remainder = "drop")
encoded_surname = transformer.fit_transform(titanic)
titanic['Encoded_Surname'] = list(encoded_surname.astype(np.float64))
```

Here is what my data frame looks like:
[image]

This is what I get when I look for the `.info()`:

```
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------           --------------  -----  
 0   Survived         891 non-null    int64  
 1   Pclass           891 non-null    int64  
 2   Sex              891 non-null    int64  
 3   SibSp            891 non-null    int64  
 4   Parch            891 non-null    int64  
 5   Fare             891 non-null    float64
 6   Encoded_Surname  891 non-null    object 
dtypes: float64(1), int64(5), object(1)
```

Since the `Encoded_Surname` label is an object and not numeric like the rest, I cannot fit the data into the classifier model.

How do I turn the `np.array` I got from `OneHotEncoder` into numeric data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, create a new dataframe for `encoded_surname` data and join it to your original dataset:

```
transformer = make_column_transformer((OneHotEncoder(sparse=False), ['Surname']), remainder = "drop")
encoded_surname = transformer.fit_transform(titanic)

titanic = titanic.join(pd.DataFrame(encoded_surname, dtype=int).add_prefix('Encoded_Surname'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use `pd.get_dummies` instead of `OneHotEncoder`.  If you really want to use the `OneHotEncoder`:

```
ohe_df = pd.DataFrame(encoded_surname, columns=transformer.get_feature_names())
#concat with original data
titanic = pd.concat([titanic, ohe_df], axis=1).drop(['Surname'], axis=1)
```

If you can use `pd.get_dummies`:

```
titanic = pd.get_dummies(titanic, prefix=['Surname'], columns=['Surname'], drop_first=True)
```